# Checking if a webpage exists on the domain, otherwise load another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Without using any server-side language, I'm trying to use JavaScript to check if a webpage exists (on the same domain, nothing cross-domain): if so, load it; if not, load another one. My code below however doesn't work, for some reason it never seems to enter the second case: instead, it always tries to load the page (typically photo_202023.html), whether it exists or not.

Worth noting (thanks to the commenter who made me realise this): the URL of the inexistent webpage loads in the browser address bar but the page that is displayed is the homepage. This is the usual behaviour whenever I try to load a webpage that doesn't exist. So it may well be that the web host (Firebase) is altering the behaviour in this case, even though the code below is the entire code I'm using.

Thank you for your help!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var today = new Date();
var displayDay = today.getDate();
var displayMonth = today.getMonth();
var displayYear = today.getFullYear();

var checkFor = "photos/photo_" + displayYear + displayMonth + displayDay + ".html";

$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: checkFor,
success: function() {
        // page exists
    location.href=checkFor;
},
error: function() {
        // page does not exist
    location.href="photosredirect.html";
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, in the network tab, what is the response to the HEAD request?

Comment: Thank you, David. Under General > Request URL: I see the value of checkFor (although that webpage doesn't exist) > Request Method: GET > Status Code: 200. Under Request Headers > Referer: the JS page with the code above > Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Comment: Sounds like, according to the server, the page does indeed exist.  There may be an issue with server-side code, maybe a server application returning custom error messages but with the wrong HTTP status codes?

Comment: Yes that's what I would understand. And yet that page doesn't exist. Ha, that makes me think: I'm using Bootstrap. The checkFor URL (that doesn't exist) does appear in the browser but the page that loads is my homepage (which is what always happens when a page is not found). So it makes me think Bootstrap could be generating the "page exists" but redirects to the homepage while displaying a "wrong" URL. So I'm not sure how to alter the behaviour in that case? Thank YOU again!

Comment: Bootstrap *server-side*?  That's not something I'm familiar with at all.  But this statement is surely telling: *"the page that loads is my homepage (which is what always happens when a page is not found)"* - That logic is in direct contradiction to what you're trying to do above.  Basically the server is being told "always return a successful response, no matter what" and the client is looking for an unsuccessful response.  Those two things will need to be reconciled.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to reconcile this. Just to be clear, the statement is based on my observation (suddenly remembering it), not something I have coded. What's more the code I put here is the integral code so I am not sure how Bootstrap would be interfering (website is only made up of static html pages, some of which are adding Bootstrap JS files). Does that make sense? Thanks again for thinking about my issue.

Comment: Whatever web host you're using has set up a rule that non-existing files get redirected to the home page. You'll need to check with your hosting provider for details on configuring this behavior.

Comment: Ah I see, yes, so nothing to do with Bootstrap, my bad. I'm hosting everything on Firebase, no special configuration.

Comment: As was stated, your web server, Firebase, is returning status `200` for every request. So your script will always be `success`. You will need to adjust the web server so that it operates with the expected status, `404`, or some other status that you can detect with a `head` request.

Comment: Yes, yes, makes sense, thank you for guiding me along the way. I see what I need to fix (don't know how yet), but firebase.json contains the following which is most likely what I need to adapt somehow:     "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so thanks to everyone who commented as they guided me to the solution: the problem was the configuration of the web host. I am hosting the code on Firebase and firebase.json was configuring what would happen in case a page wasn't found i.e. redirecting to index.html. I removed that rewrite and the code works as intended.

I did want to try and be more subtle, to keep that default behaviour for all pages not inside /photos/ nor photos.html (which contains the code mentioned above), but I must be doing something wrong still – but that's for another topic! Thanks again to all the commenters.

```
"rewrites": [
{
// Excludes specified pathways from rewrites
"source": "!/photos/**",
"destination": "/index.html"
}
    , {
// Excludes specified pathways from rewrites
"source": "!/photos.html",
"destination": "/index.html"
}
,
      {
// If it makes it here, it didn't match any previous routing
// Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
"source": "**",
"destination": "/index.html"
}
```